# Entity Framework 4 - How is ObjectContext.Refresh() supposed to work?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, objectcontext

When I call Refresh using RefreshMode.StoreWins on an entity that is in my context and the values in the database are different than what the entity currently holds, is my entity supposed to update the currentvalues to that of the database even if my objects entitystate is unchanged?

When editing an entity we instantiate a new context and instantiate a new ourClass(classId) which loads the current entity of our class type from the database. Making changes to ourClass and calling SaveChanges correctly saves the values to the database. After returning to the calling viewmodel, we call Refresh on the pre-existing context using RefreshMode.StoreWins but this is not updating the values of the entities in this context despite seeing that the values in the database were correctly updated using SSMS. Any ideas what I should be looking into for solving this issue?

**EDIT:**
Simple example of how we are doing things:

```
var context1 = new Model1();
LoadContext(); //loads all the data from the database and adds them to the context
var context2 = new Model1();
var SelectedObject = context1.Table1.First();
OurObject selectedObjectForEdit = new OurObject(SelectedObject.ObjectId);
context2.Table1.Add(selectedObjectForEdit);
selectedObjectForEdit.Name = "new name";
context2.SaveChanges();
context1.Refresh(RefreshMode.StoreWins, SelectedObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

You must attention to a context refresh a entity that is in **self context** not other context, Refresh a entity with other context run manually **without any exception** and nothing any change occurred even with SoreWins.

```
var context1 = new Model1();
var context2 = new Model1();
context1.Table1.First().Caption = "a";
var entity = context2.Table1.First();
context1.SaveChanges();
//below code run without exception but any change not affected
context1.Refresh(RefreshMode.StoreWins, entity);
```

context1 force to refresh a entity that's included in context2.

Comment: Your answer confuses me a little bit. Are you saying that StoreWins only updates an entity that is in the EntityState.Modified state?

Comment: My intention is you shouldn't refresh a entity with a another context, I add a sample, wait...

Comment: We are calling context1.Refresh(RefreshMode.StoreWins, originalEntity) not using the entity from context2. The 2nd context and 2nd entity live and die in our DetailViewModel whereas our original entity and context persist in our ListViewModel. The changes occur in DetailViewModel and I'm wondering if refreshing the original context is possible when the entities will always remain in an EntityState.Unchanged. So we aren't calling context1.Refresh using the entity attached to the second context but rather the original entity that is attached to the first context.

Comment: Debug your Refresh line code and see if IntelliTrace execute any query when Refresh is called. commonly ought not have a problem with your scenario!!

Comment: Are executed any query when Refresh is called? Where is the problem?

Comment: The issue turned out to be that Refresh only refreshes the properties that aren't objects themselves. I had to step through the properties that were collections of other objects calling refresh on each of those as well. I wouldn't have realized this if I hadn't looked at the query being run using IntelliTrace, so thank you.